# using memorystream for media element in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, video, stream

I am trying to add a video to a project in WP7.
I'm downloading the data needed, put it an a bytearray, just like I do with an image. But then when I call `MediaElement.SetSource( new MemoryStream( result, 0, result.Length ) );` I get a NotSupportedException. Stream must be of type IsolatedStorageFileStream. Is there a possibility to play the element using a memory stream? Because it would be much simpeler, as I'm not going to use the video afterwards, and do not want to store it what soever.

Answer (score 3):

If you check [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426928%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) about media in Silverlight for the Windows Phone, you can read the following:

Passing a generic stream to SetSource(Stream) is not supported. To use SetSource(Stream) on Windows Phone OS 7.0:

- Pass an object of type IsolatedStorageFileStream to the method.
- Copy the generic stream to isolated storage, and then pass it as an
  object of type IsolatedStorageFileStream.

So it is not possible. You could delete the file from the isolatedstorage after you have used it.

Comment: Damn, that sucks. I already have some performance problems when downloading and caching images =[